# Audio and video are out of sync using the WebRTC MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, mediarecorder

When using the MediaRecorder API on both Chrome and Firefox, I've experienced that the audio is about 100ms-300ms ahead of the video, enough to be noticeable for someone talking. I've been using `type: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'` for the transcoding. The amount to be varies based on the computer, but there seems to always be at least a small delay. These are the specs I use, and I don't adjust the bitrate, given the bugs in Chrome.

```
const constraints = {
  video: { height: 240, width: 320 },
  audio: true,
};
```

I don't think the problem is isolated to me, as testing on type: https://simpl.info/mediarecorder/ also seems to show a similar problem, but I haven't seen it discussed anywhere.

I ended up just adjusting the transcoding to account for the delay, but obviously I'd prefer to tackle the problem at its source.